# Add progress bar to uploader

Tags: php, progress-bar, uploader

I have a built a php uploader. I want to improve it by adding a progress bar. How do I add a progress bar? (obviously not in php because php is server side). What language do I need to use and how do I use it?

Comment: Try Bootstrap! http://getbootstrap.com

Comment: http://www.w3bees.com/2013/10/file-upload-with-progress-bar.html

Comment: Questions describing your requirements and asking someone to write the code for you or explain to you how to write the code are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Please identify a specific problem or question about programming. Include attempted solutions, an explanation of how the results differed from the expected results, and any error messages you received. Please read this: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use JQuery. This is an example: http://www.w3bees.com/2013/10/file-upload-with-progress-bar.html